# setting colors for individual bars

Tags: r, ggplot2, colors

I'm having trouble setting the colors of my bar graph. Here is the code I am using. When the graph prints, all the bars default to gray.

```
a<- c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e")
b<- rnorm(5)
A<-data.frame(a,b)
group.colors <- c(a= "blue", 
                  b= "orange", 
                  c= "blue",
                  d = "orange", 
                  e = "orange")
A%>%ggplot(aes(a)) +
  geom_bar() +
  scale_fill_manual(group.colors)
```

Comment: Please make your example [reproducible](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Comment: Thanks for tip. Now reproducible.

Answer (score 1):

You need to map a variable to the `fill` aesthetic, otherwise changing `scale_fill_manual` has no effect since there is no no scale which could be filled:

```
ggplot(A, aes(a, fill = a)) +
  geom_bar() +
  scale_fill_manual(values = group.colors)
```